# Singular correlation matrix implies linear dependence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, covariance

Given a random vector $X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_n\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose that $R = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$ is the correlation matrix of the random vector $X$

> We claim that if $R$ is singular, then the components of $X$ must
>   not be linearly independent (i.e. they are linearly dependent).

Does anyone see how to prove this claim? I've tried some thought experiments (e.g. when $R$ is diagonal) but I couldn't see how you would go about proving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $R$ is singular, then there exists a non-zero vector $v$ so that $Rv = 0$; multiplying on the left by $v^T$ then gives $v^T Rv = 0$.  Substituting the definition of $R$ in gives $$0 = v^T R v = v^T\mathbb{E}[XX^T]v = \mathbb{E}[v^TX X^Tv] = \mathbb{E}[| X \cdot v |^2].$$
Since $\mathbb{E}[|X \cdot v|^2] = 0,$ this implies that $X \cdot v = 0$ almost surely, i.e. $X$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Why $X \cdot v$ almost surely? Aren't you showing that it converges to $0$ in the mean square sense?

Comment: There's no convergence happening here: $X\cdot v$ is a random variable, and we showed that it's second moment is zero.  This then implies that it is equal to zero almost surely (by Chebyshev's inequality).

Comment: Then let $X_n = X \cdot v$ (this is a constant sequence). $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[|(X_n - 0)|^2] = \mathbb{E}[|X \cdot v|^2] = 0$ implies that the constant sequence $X_n$ converges to $0$ in the mean square sense.

Comment: I don't see why you'd gain anything from thinking of it as a constant sequence.  Having second moment equaling zero means that it *is* equal to zero.